# MySQL Java prepared statement Syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I need to select rows from mysql table based on various criteria, for example Colour= Black, or size= L.

The code works without the preparedstatement and the question marks, but whenever I attempt to use the question marks the code does not run.

I have read something about typing the question mark like \'?'// but I am not sure about the exact format.

```
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clothing";
String USERNAME = "root";
String PASSWORD = "password";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql= "SELECT * FROM clothing.Lostandfound WHERE Colour = ? AND Size = ?;";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStmt.setString(1, Data1);
preparedStmt.setString(2, Data2);
```

Also, Size is written out in orange colour, but the error happens also when I only use this sql String

```
String sql= "SELECT * FROM clothing.Lostandfound WHERE Colour = ?;";
```

I have looked at like 20 different answers, but didnt find anything helpful, so thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You don't have to escape the `?`. You forgot to include the actual error message. However the problem is here: `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);`. It should be `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();`. The former is not a method of `PreparedStatement`. It is inherited from `Statement`; ignores the statement preparation steps; and doesn't know about `?`.

Comment: @user207421 Why don’t you make an Answer of your Comment so we might mark this page as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the query using a normal `java.sql.Statement`, not using a `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. This won't work because a normal `Statement` does not support parameterized queries. So, remove the creation and execution of the `Statement`, and make sure you execute the statement using the `PreparedStatement`:

```java
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clothing";
String USERNAME = "root";
String PASSWORD = "password";
String sql= "SELECT * FROM clothing.Lostandfound WHERE Colour = ? AND Size = ?;";
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
     PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    preparedStmt.setString(1, Data1);
    preparedStmt.setString(2, Data2);
    try (ResultSet rs = preparedStmt.executeQuery()) {
        // process result set
    }
}
```

Also note the addition of try-with-resources, which will ensure connections, statements and result sets are closed correctly.

Comment: By the way, do you know how I could also use the prepared statement ? for the names of the columns? Like replacing Colour and Size with a ? aswell. I read on another answer that ? can not replace table names or column names, but I still wanted to ask... Otherwise I will have to use a lot of if statements to actually let the user set the Column he wants to compare the data in... Thank you!!!

Comment: @XXXMathematicianXXX You can only parametrize **values**, parametrizing object names like table or column names is not possible.